# Getting Lost in Prototype Method Calls

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, this

apologies I realise there are a number of other threads that describe similar issues however I have not been able to find one that answers my question fully (at least in a way that I understand).

I use the following code to create an Object which manages the UI interactions for the various complicated instances of an input Form across my site.

Using Prototypes, I effectively end up with an object called **categoryForm** with various methods contained within:
- **categoryForm.addEventListeners**
- **categoryForm.handlers**
- **categoryForm.validation**

The last two are objects containing a number of different Methods.
The below code is a cut down version of my finished code, however should be sufficient to get the problem across, as the rest is variations on a similar theme.

The Issue I have is that, in the below example:
- I click '.addNewItems' on my table
- This triggers my listener, which calls the 'addNewTableItem' handler method.
- The handler then attempts to Loop through the Inputs, passing them through  the 'validation.checkInputVal' method to validate each input before proceeding.

However, by the time we're in this loop, the scope of **this** has totally changed (as expected) and I have no idea how to refer to my categoryForm Object and call the 'validation.checkInputVal' method. I just get an error saying that this is not a function.(again expected)

Here's the code:

```
function categoryFormFuncs(){

    // VARIABLES
    var _this               = this;
    var table               = $('table');

    // EVENT LISTENER FUNCTIONS
    this.addEventListeners = function(){

        // Listen for the AddItemButton on Tables and call the addNewTableItem function
        table.on('click', '.addNewItems', function(e){
            // Find new ItemGroup and Collect Inputs into an Array
            var newItemGroup = $(this).parents('.newItemGroup')[0];
            // Send New Item Group and Table to be updated to the Handler
            _this.handlers.addNewTableItem(newItemGroup);
        });


    }
};

// HANDLER FUNCTIONS
categoryFormFuncs.prototype.handlers = {

        // Function to Create a NewItemGroup table row
        addNewTableItem: function (inputGroup){
            var validationcheck;
            // Get all the Inputs
            var inputs = $(inputGroup).find('input');
            // Check Inputs are valid and Highlight them if not
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
                validationcheck = validation.checkInputVal(inputs[i]);
                if(!validationcheck.passed){
                    $(inputs[i]).addClass('input-inValid')
                    return
                } else {
                    $(inputs[i]).removeClass('input-inValid')
                }
            };
            // If Valid, turn each input into a Table Cell and clear the original Input value
            var rowCells = ""
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
                rowCells += "<td>" + $(inputs[i]).val() + "</td>";
                $(inputs[i]).val("");
            }
            // Construct the new Table row and update the DOM
            var newRow = "<tr class='itemGroup'>" + rowCells + "<td><span class='float-right remove-item fa fa-minus-circle'></span></td></tr>";
            $(inputGroup).before(newRow);
        }
}


// VALIDATION CHECKS
categoryFormFuncs.prototype.validation = {

        checkInputVal: function(input){
            if($(input).val()){
                return { passed: true }
            } else {
                return { passed: false, message: "Input with no Value"}
            }   
        }
}

var categoryForm = new categoryFormFuncs();
categoryForm.addEventListeners();
```

I have found one way to make this work which is to provide the validation method as an argument to the Handler:

```
function categoryFormFuncs(){

    // VARIABLES
    var _this               = this;
    var table               = $('table');

    // EVENT LISTENER FUNCTIONS
    this.addEventListeners = function(){

        // Listen for the AddItemButton on Tables and call the addNewTableItem function
        table.on('click', '.addNewItems', function(e){
            // Find new ItemGroup and Collect Inputs into an Array
            var newItemGroup = $(this).parents('.newItemGroup')[0];
            // Send New Item Group and Table to be updated to the Handler
            _this.handlers.addNewTableItem(newItemGroup, _this.validation.checkInputVal);
        });


    }
};

// handlers
categoryFormFuncs.prototype.handlers = {

        // Function to Create a NewItemGroup table row
        addNewTableItem: function (inputGroup, checkInputVal){
            var validationcheck;
            // Get all the Inputs
            var inputs = $(inputGroup).find('input');
            // Check Inputs are valid and Highlight them if not
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
                validationcheck = checkInputVal(inputs[i]);
                if(!validationcheck.passed){
                    $(inputs[i]).addClass('input-inValid')
                    return
                } else {
                    $(inputs[i]).removeClass('input-inValid')
                }
            };
            // If Valid, turn each input into a Table Cell and clear the original Input value
            var rowCells = ""
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
                rowCells += "<td>" + $(inputs[i]).val() + "</td>";
                $(inputs[i]).val("");
            }
            // Construct the new Table row and update the DOM
            var newRow = "<tr class='itemGroup'>" + rowCells + "<td><span class='float-right remove-item fa fa-minus-circle'></span></td></tr>";
            $(inputGroup).before(newRow);
        }
}


// VALIDATION CHECKS
categoryFormFuncs.prototype.validation = {

        checkInputVal: function(input){
            if($(input).val()){
                return { passed: true }
            } else {
                return { passed: false, message: "Input with no Value"}
            }   
        }
}

var categoryForm = new categoryFormFuncs();
categoryForm.addEventListeners();
```

Alternatively I could also pass a reference to _this from the listener to the handler in order to access _this.validation.
Either way these all feel like very messy and clunky solutions.

My question is:
a) Is there a way, using my original deisgn to access the validation methods?
b) Is there a better established pattern for this type of Lister / Handler / Validation scenario that I should know about?

(Disclaimer: I am very new to programming (6 months) so apologies if my description is incorrect in any way.

Comment: Have you tried to define your validation inside categoryFormFuncs instead of using prototype ?

Comment: That's a good point, it would give me access to my _this variable!
I think the reason I'd separated the handlers and validations off onto the Prototype was because there are pages that have multiple form and table elements and didn't want to weigh the browser down with handlers being attached to each instance of the element.
That said I'm probably just underestimating the power of modern browsers and complicating my script in the process!?

Comment: Up to you :) But IMO I would have done this !

Comment: I think you're spot on tbh. Trying to be clever and complicating things where it's not necessary I think! Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't forget to update the status :) Bye